# CanCan authorize all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan

I have CanCan and Rolify set up with ActiveAdmin, and now it's time to force authorization on my controllers.

Do I have to `authorize_resource` on every controller (We have a couple dozen models and controllers now), or is there a way to apply it to all of my ActiveAdmin controllers?

I tried calling it in a before_filter from ActiveAdmin.setup, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an initializer: config/initializers/active_admin-cancan.rb

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController    
    # If you don't skip loading on #index you will get the exception:
    #
    #     "Collection is not a paginated scope. Set collection.page(params[:page]).per(10) before calling :paginated_collection."

    load_resource :except => :index
    authorize_resource

    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.accessible_by(current_ability)
    end
  end
end
```

Borrowed from another user's code, but now I can't find the source any more.